# Does the Microsoft Sync Framework update the schema and data or just the data?

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

Does the Microsoft Sync Framework update the schema and data or just the data ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync Framework doesnt do schema synchronization if that's what you're after. just data synchronization.

so if you have a table with 2 columns on two replicas and you add another column on one replica, that schema change wont be reflected on the second replica.

it might even break your sync.